# Symfony2 - Field not existent when using Event Subscribers

Tags: forms, events, symfony

I'm trying to implement dependable forms, I followed [this](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/) and it pretty much seems it just doesn't find the fields.

View:

```
<form action="{{ path('select_users') }}" method="POST" novalidate>
                                                    {{ form_row(form.company) }}
                                                    {{ form_row(form.user) }}
                                                    {{ form_rest(form) }}
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                                    Next
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
```

Error:

```
Method "company" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in EngMgmtBundle:Engineering:update.html.twig at line 110
```

Note: I'm not using the "Location" Model used in the example, because I don't need an extra field or another entity. (at least I think I don't)

I'm using version 2.3

What i'm trying to accomplish: User selects company, the user field should fill only with the users that belong to the selected company.

Form:

```
    class UsersForCompanyType extends AbstractType
    {
            /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();
            $companySubscriber = new AddCompanyFieldSubscriber($factory);
            $builder->addEventSubscriber($companySubscriber);
            $userSubscriber = new AddUserFieldSubscriber($factory);
            $builder->addEventSubscriber($userSubscriber);
            $builder->add('comments', 'textarea', array (
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Comments:'
                    ));
        }
        /**
         * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
         */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Company'
            ));
        }
        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'users_for_company';
        }
    }
```

Company Subscriber:

```
class AddCompanyFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_BIND     => 'preBind'
        );
    }

    private function addCompanyForm($form, $company)
    {
        $form->add('company', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'UserBundle:Company',
            'mapped'        => false,
            'data'          => $company,
            'empty_value'   => 'Company',
            'attr'          => array(
                'class' => 'company_selector',
            ),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('company');

                return $qb;
            }
        ));
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $accessor = PropertyAccess::getPropertyAccessor();
        $user = $accessor->getValue($data, 'user');
        $company = ($data->getUser()) ? $data->getUser()->getCompany() : null ;
        $this->addCompanyForm($form, $company);
    }

    public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $company = array_key_exists('company', $data) ? $data['company'] : null;
        $this->addCompanyForm($form, $company);
    }
```

User Subscriber: 
    class AddUserFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        private $factory;

```
    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_BIND     => 'preBind'
        );
    }

    private function addUserForm($form, $user, $company)
    {
        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('user','entity', null, array(
            'class'         => 'UserBundle:User',
            'empty_value'   => 'Select User',
            'data'          => $user,
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'attr'          => array(
            'class' => 'user_selector',
            ),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($company) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('user')
                    ->innerJoin('user.company', 'company');
                if ($company instanceof Company) {
                    $qb->where('user.company = :company')
                    ->setParameter('company', $company);
                } elseif (is_numeric($company)) {
                    $qb->where('company.id = :company')
                    ->setParameter('company', $company);
                } else {
                    $qb->where('company.name = :company')
                    ->setParameter('company', null);
                }

                return $qb;
            }
        )));
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }
        $accessor = PropertyAccess::getPropertyAccessor();
        $user = $accessor->getValue($data, 'user');
        $company = ($data->getUser()) ? $data->getUser()->getCompany() : null ;
        $this->addUserForm($form, $user, $company);
    }

    public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $company = array_key_exists('company', $data) ? $data['company'] : null;
        $user = array_key_exists('user', $data) ? $data['user'] : null;
        $this->addUserForm($form, $user, $company);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but have you tried {{ dump() }} in your twig-template to see what variables you have there available?

It's just a long shot, but in the preBind() function you are checking if the keys 'user' and 'company' exist in $data so my guess is, that in your twig-template you should use

```
{{ form_row(company) }} {# instead of {{ form_row(form.company) }} #}
{{ form_row(user) }} {# instead of {{ form_row(form.user) }} #}
```